# crossing path of two rail

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

let us consider following problem

Two trains starting from cities $300$ miles apart head in opposite directions at rates of $70$ mph and $50$ mph, respectively. How long does it take the trains to cross paths?

i would like to  first of all determine geometrical picture of this problem,is it  this one?
[image]

here $300$  denoted length between sises?if it is correct then  i dont know exactly how could i solve,suppose that  they cross   after $t$ hour,then first one would have passed $70*t$  second one  $300-50*t$,so equation would be  $70t=300-50*t$,or $120t=300$  from which $t$ is equal to $2.5$ is it correct?

Comment: Can you please add labels to indicate the starting points & directions

Comment: i have done it on   paint,direction is to each other

Comment: I think, your picture is wrong. The trains drive exactly towards each other (on a straight line towards the other city), not in some angle (otherwise, you would need more information in order to solve this).

Comment: this one?i have uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct in calculation .They head in opposite directions means exact opposite

so $$ 70 \times t + 50 \times t = 300 $$

$$ t = 2.5 hours $$[image]

Red guy travels at 70 miles/hr and green guy travels at 50 miles/hr. so they meet at 2.5 hrs at a distance 175 miles from red guys starting place and 125 miles from green guys starting place.

Comment: i have changed diagram,i did not pay attention on diagram

Comment: which program you have used? nice color like  rainbow.

Comment: MS PAINT is used . I used colours so that it adds effect and really easy to understand

Comment: yes very nice thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The picture is wrong because the trains are on the same set of tracks, traveling in opposite directions.  There should be no triangle.

Your answer of 2.5 is correct if you say that it is $2.5\ \bf{ hours}$.  Just "$2.5$" by itself is wrong.

Comment: yes of course hour,it is asked about hour

Comment: No, it isn't.  The question you asked was "How long does it take the trains to cross paths?" It was not "How many hours does it take the trains to cross paths."